# DYLD_LIBRARY_LOAD_PATH vs LD_LIBRARY_LOAD_PATH

Tags: gcc, environment-variables, dynamic-linking

What's the difference between the following:

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_LOAD_PATH
LD_LIBRARY_LOAD_PATH
LIBRARY_LOAD_PATH
```

Are these platform specific?  Does only the DYLD* env. variable deal with dynamic linking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes they are Os- specific

> DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH

is for the mac library linker

> LD_LIBRARY_PATH

is for the general Linux library linker